# Why cant we select any properties on the many side when we are using .Select(x=>new object) on Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

i just wonder about something which has no sense to me. I'm using ASP.NET Core 5.0 and im using Linq.

I have a two class which has relationship `One (MainCategory) - To - (Category) Many`.  I wanna write a linq which is gonna targeting to get `MainCategoryName` and `CategoryID`. Let me show to you my linq :

```
public IEnumerable<MainCategory> GetMainCategoryForFair()
{
    return DBContext.MainCategories.Where(x => x.MainCategoryIsFeatured == true
        && x.IsDeleted != true)
        .Select(x => new MainCategory
        {
            MainCategoryName = x.MainCategoryName,
            Categories = x.Categories
        }).ToList();
}
```

I know, that query gonna take all properties of `Categories` and this is the thing im trying to avoid. Is it possible ?

if it's possible,then how ?

if it's not, why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Just don't project all the properties.  And normally if you are returning a different data shape, you would introduce a new class to return, instead of returning an Entity type with a bunch of null properties, eg

```
public IEnumerable<MainCategoryDTO> GetMainCategoryForFair()
{
    return DBContext.MainCategories.Where(x => x.MainCategoryIsFeatured == true
        && x.IsDeleted != true)
        .Select(x => new MainCategoryDTO()
        {
            MainCategoryName = x.MainCategoryName,
            Categories = x.Categories.Select( c => new CategoryDTO(){CategoryName = c.Name, ...}).ToList()
        }).ToList();
}
```